# node-soap -- how to capture soap request before it is handled by soap listener

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, wsdl, node-soap

I created a soap server in nodejs using the [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) module.  But I get an error indicating there is some problem in the incoming soap xml (listed below).

> < soap log: { Fault:  <    { faultcode: 500, <      faultstring:
>   'Invalid XML', <      detail: 'Error: Non-whitespace before first
>   tag.\nLine: 1\nColumn: 1\nChar: -', <      statusCode: undefined } }

When I searched around in google, it indicated that it is the problem of BOM (Byte Order Mark) which the windows OS inserts into the unicode buffer.  Most of the solutions suggested to replace/remove this BOM before calling the xml parser.

[image]

Now, when I am using node-soap module, I am unable to figure out where to apply this fix, below being my server code.

```
/**
 * Simple demonstration of soap service
 **/

var soapService = require("./rv.js");

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('./mmsxmlpushservicews.wsdl.xml', 'utf8');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var soap = require('soap');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: function() { return true; }, limit: '5mb' }));
app.listen(8001, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("error:", err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  var server = soap.listen(app, '/smshttp/soapws', soapService, xml); 
  server.log = function(type, data) {
    //console.log("soap log:", data);
  }
  console.log("service running on port 8001...");
});
```

- In the above soap server code, is there an event / callback hook that I can make use of to modify the soap request buffer, before the soap server performs its parsing?
- If yes, where and how should I be doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code after this line  'app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: function() { return true; }, limit: '5mb' }));'

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var body = req.body.toString();
    var body = body.replace('\ufeff', '');
    req.body = Buffer.from(body);
    next();
});
```

This hook in express allows you process every request, evaluate which urls have been called and safely forward to the next listener with 'next()'.

But consider that this function will be called for EVERY request, so don't forget to filter only those, where you do need to clean the string.